# i have two columns from two different tables where date will be stored in different formats. how can i caliculate difference between both of them

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables like table1, table2 which consists of C1, C2 respectively.

> C1 is of varchar2 type and stores date in 01/01/1989 format.
>
> C2 is of Date type stores data in 24-May-2016 00:00:00 format.

i want to get the date difference between both the columns and calculate the years of difference between both. Please let me know how?

Comment: Fix the data in the first table to use the correct type.  That is really the best approach.

Comment: So it `table1.c1` is that "date" `jan-01-1989` or `01-jan-1989`? How do you know?

Comment: Why, oh why are you storing a `DATE` as a `varchar`. Don't do that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('24-May-2016 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
 TO_DATE('01/01/1989','MM/DD/YYYY'))/12)  FROM dual;
```

You need to replace field name and table as below:

```
SELECT FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE(t2.datefield,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
TO_DATE(t1.datestringfield,'MM/DD/YYYY'))/12)  FROM table t1 INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.id = t2.id;
```